# form_for doesn't get correct routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, form-for

I have a search form, but when I click the search button, it doesn't get the correct url:

```
<%= form_for search_leads_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

it should be go to the `/leads/search`, but it is still in `/leads`

**rake routes:**

```
....
      search_leads GET    /leads/search(.:format)                                 leads#search
             leads GET    /leads(.:format)                                        leads#index
....
```

anyone has good idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: first argument should be  the object and then define your custom url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this -

first argument should be the object and then define your custom url.

```
<%= form_for(:search, url: search_leads_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

for more info check here
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: if you don't have object like @search then you can define ':search' as symbol first argument.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`form_for` expects the first argument be a resource, for example `@user`. Which works well for the Restful routes. But as this is a custom route, you should use `form_tag` instead.

Try updating your form logic to the following:

```
<%= form_tag search_leads_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Refer to [FormTagHelper#form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) for more info.